# Выводит последнюю информацию в textbox

Tags: c#

Делаю приложение и возникла проблема:

```
public void StartServer()
    {
        string IP=textBox1.Text;
        int pport=int.Parse(textBox3.Text.ToString());
        IPAddress _ip = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_ip, pport);
        Socket listSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listSocket.Bind(iPEndPoint);
            listSocket.Listen(20);
            Action action = () => { 
                 textBox2.Text = "Server is running" + Environment.NewLine;
textBox2.Text = "Test text";
             };
            Invoke(action);
            while (true)
            {
                Socket handle = listSocket.Accept();
                StringBuilder stringbuild = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                byte[] info = new byte[512];
                do
                {
                    bytes = handle.Receive(info);
                    stringbuild.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(info, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (handle.Available > 0);
                //textBox2.Text=(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + stringbuild.ToString());
                string message = "Данные успешно занесены";
                info = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                handle.Send(info);
                handle.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handle.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка :" + ex);
        }
    }
```

В блоке Action есть 2 свойства для добавления текста. Проблема в том что выводит в textbox только последнее свойство тоесть в моём случае будет выводить textBox2.Text = "Test text" а не все вместе. Скажите с чем это связано? Может кто знает как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А вы что ожидаете? Вы используете присвоение, то есть "мой текст теперь будет "Test test" ". Хотите добавление к уже имеющему или что? Почитайте про [операторы](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level3/3_11.php)

Comment: Точно. Изменил оператор на += и все заработало. Чёт затупу словил я)